# How should I format the acl spec for webhdfs rest interface - op=SETACL

Tags: rest, interface, hdfs, azure-storage, webhdfs

The example at this link does not explain how to format the aclspec:  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Set_ACL

I have tried several different ways to format and I keep getting an error :

```
 "Invalid ACL: the user, group and other entries are required"
```

I am sending ACLs like :

```
other::r-x
user:15b70438-f54b-4d7d-95aa-74afe8e1a09f:rwx
group::rwx
group:231db2e5-792c-4788-8abc-2187d7233ea8:r-x
```

etc

Here's the Scala Circe code:

```
   val aclPermResp= sttp
       .auth.bearer(accessString)
       .body(Map("Content-Length" -> "0"))
       .put(uri"https://$dlStorageName.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/$path?op=SETACL&aclspec=$oLine")
   aclPermResp.send().unsafeBody
```

Here's what getaclstatus returns:

```
{  
   "AclStatus":{  
      "entries":[  
         "user:15b70438-f54b-4d7d-95aa-74afe8e1a09f:rwx",
         "user:6fca950f-3ac4-495e-b9cf-ae55af2f5b11:rwx",
         "user:dcb7b874-eeb0-44f6-8088-d1ff65a69807:rwx",
         "user:fadc0eee-f2af-4e1b-b0c7-f7d2059ef065:rwx",
         "group::rwx",
         "group:231db2e5-792c-4788-8abc-2187d7233ea8:r-x",
         "group:7c24b109-edf2-422e-b20e-df8095043b93:rwx",
         "group:ec768852-cc88-40f2-91a8-3e57b5ee4a79:r-x",
         "default:user::rwx",
         "default:user:15b70438-f54b-4d7d-95aa-74afe8e1a09f:rwx",
         "default:user:6fca950f-3ac4-495e-b9cf-ae55af2f5b11:rwx",
         "default:user:dcb7b874-eeb0-44f6-8088-d1ff65a69807:rwx",
         "default:user:fadc0eee-f2af-4e1b-b0c7-f7d2059ef065:rwx",
         "default:group::rwx",
         "default:group:231db2e5-792c-4788-8abc-2187d7233ea8:r-x",
         "default:group:7c24b109-edf2-422e-b20e-df8095043b93:rwx",
         "default:mask::rwx",
         "default:other::---"
      ],
      "owner":"6fca950f-3ac4-495e-b9cf-ae55af2f5b11",
      "group":"7c24b109-edf2-422e-b20e-df8095043b93",
      "permission":"777",
      "stickyBit":false
   }
}
```

I tried modifying this existing ACL and sending it back as the aclspec but that doesn't work either. It returns the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

The `acl_spec` must include entries for the user, group, and others for compatibility with permission bits. 
For example:

```
"user::rw-,user:hadoop:rw-,group::r--,other::r--"
```